# How will I be able to validate the column value from the table and merge into the another table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
CREATE TABLE c_file (
    e_id   NUMBER(10),
    ac_ec  VARCHAR2(100),
    constraint pk_c_file primary key(e_id)
);

insert into c_file values(1,'A');
insert into c_file values(2,'A');
insert into c_file values(3,'E');
insert into c_file values(4,'A');
insert into c_file values(5,'E');

CREATE TABLE e_staging (
    e_id   NUMBER(10),
    ac_ec  VARCHAR2(100)
);

insert into e_staging values(1,null);
insert into e_staging values(2,null);
insert into e_staging values(3,null);
insert into e_staging values(4,null);
insert into e_staging values(5,null);
insert into e_staging values(6,null);
insert into e_staging values(7,null);
insert into e_staging values(8,null);
insert into e_staging values(9,null);
insert into e_staging values(10,null);

CREATE TABLE e_details (
    e_id   NUMBER(10),
    ac_ec  VARCHAR2(100)
);
```

Merge :

```
MERGE INTO e_details m
USING (
          SELECT
              e_id,
              ac_ec
          FROM
              e_staging
      )
s ON ( m.e_id = s.e_id )
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
SET m.ac_ec = s.ac_ec
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (
    e_id,
    ac_ec )
VALUES
    ( s.e_id,
      s.ac_ec );
```

Issue :

By this Merge, it will load all the data from the e_staging table but while loading
it should check the e_id into the c_file table if the e_id is present in c_file and in the e_staging table
then it should update the ac_ec column based on the c_file ac_ec column if e_id is not present in e_staging then
it should be updated to 'E'.

Current output :

[image: Current output coming as]

Expected Output :

[image: Expected Output]

For e_id 1 - While loading into the e_details table from the e_staging table. It should check in
the c_file table. If e_id is present then should update the ac_ec column to A.
Likewise for all the e_id till 5.

From e_id 6 to 10. These are not present in c_file so value to be updated to 'E'.

Tool: SQL Developer
Version: 20.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join to c_file in the `USING` block of the `MERGE` statement.

```
MERGE INTO e_details m
USING (
        SELECT
            e.e_id,
            NVL(c.ac_ec,'E') AS ac_ec
        FROM
            e_staging e LEFT OUTER JOIN c_file c ON e.e_id = c.e_id  
      )
s ON ( m.e_id = s.e_id )
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
SET m.ac_ec = s.ac_ec
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (
    e_id,
    ac_ec )
VALUES
    ( s.e_id,
      s.ac_ec );
```

Comment: Thanks it worked for me. Could you please explain why we have used left outer join

Comment: left join is because you want to have a row in the resultset for every row in e_staging. You don't want inner join (only rows that exist in both tables) or right join (all rows in c_file even if they don't exist in e_staging).